# How can I query the Created Date of a Custom Metadata Record?

Tags: apex, soql, custom-metadata

I want to query the Created Date of a Custom Metadata Record. I'm trying this:

```
SELECT Id, DeveloperName, CreatedDate FROM Interest__mdt ORDER BY CreatedDate LIMIT 1
```

But I'm getting this error:

> No such column 'CreatedDate' on entity 'Interest__mdt'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

How can i get the last record? Thanks!

Comment: Can you Check Tooling Api option in Developer console and try to fetch the created date alone in query?

Comment: Using Tooling Api show me this: `sObject type 'Interest__mdt' is not supported.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have only these standard fields on Custom Metadata record:

- DeveloperName
- Id
- Label
- Language
- MasterLabel
- NamespacePrefix
- QualifiedApiName

My sugestion is creating a custom field that you can Order by in the way that it is good for you.

Comment: Thanks! My workarround was create a custom field named `CreatedDate` with a default value of `NOW()`. But i'm interested in use a better standard option.

Comment: For now, no standard solution.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'm going to open an idea.

Comment: good idea! Post here and I will vote it up!

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CYqVQAW